# Toggle between multiple div's or similar to tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a custom tab which has animated bottom border which slides from one tab to another in

Example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxNZLv

```
<div class="tab-nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">ONE</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">TWO</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">THREE</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content-wrapper">
  <div class="tab1-c"><p>This is ONE</p></div> 
  <div class="tab2-c"><p>This is TWO</p></div> 
  <div class="tab3-c"><p>This is THREE</p></div> 
  <div class="tab4-c"><p>This is FOUR</p></div> 

<div>
```

I want related items to show based on what ever tab is clicked. I tried to make it work but got errors.

Event tried to convert this into bootstrap tabs that didn't either work. It breaks the animation that i want on tabs

Boostrap based example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVzjJo

I have updated fiddle and wrote script for each tab. rather than i wanted single script to manage it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxNZLv

Can we improve it?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/yeOdrq?editors=101)?

Comment: @alirezasafian, Thanks this what i want looking to do exactly.  It you will put it as answer so that i can mark it as correct answer

Comment: I'll do and I didn't get you downvote. I'll give upvote to understand me.

Comment: @alirezasafian, It is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `index` of the clicked element by jquery [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and then use jquery [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to show a tab content according the index of clicked element.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/alireza-safian/pen/yeOdrq?editors=101)

**Note: both function are zero-based, you don't need to plus one.**

```
$('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){  
  $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
 $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I made a fork of your example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrqVXb

It assigns a data attribute, which you can easily read with jQuery, which determines which `div` it should open, and hides all the rest.

Comment: I also make it working with individual script. your script makes scene. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxNZLv

Answer (score 3):

Try this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeOmLR

**JavaScript:**

```
var cn = function(self) {
    return (self).className.substr(4);
  },
  tcw = $('.tab-content-wrapper');

$('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li').click(function() {
  tcw.children().hide();
  tcw.children('.tab' + cn(this) + '-c').show()
});
```

I changed your tabs' classes to more workable and readable names.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling between multiple divs with similar tab

No bootstrap included within this code

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/mozeyo/edit?html,output)
JSBIN

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

//get displaying tab content jQuery selector
var active_tab_selector = $('.nav-tabs > li.active > a').attr('href');

//find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > li.active');
actived_nav.removeClass('active');

//add 'active' css into clicked navigation
$(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

//hide displaying tab content
$(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
$(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');

//show target tab content
var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
$(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
$(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
});
});
```